Installing GRUB on a different disc
I'm not sure what does the "Device for bootloader installation" do exactly. My Ubuntu install is on a separate drive but I'd rather put a separate EFI partition on an SSD and have kernels and all that stuff load from an SSD. I also have a separate Windows partition and its EFI on there so I removed boot and esp flags from it in hopes that Windows loader wouldn't override GRUB.
So... The question is, how would I go about doing all that. Do I create /boot on my SSD and use it as an install path, Do I NOT create any /boot partitions and just pick the nvme0 drive, I'm used to partitioning /boot and /efi instead of /boot/efi, maybe I create /efi on my SSD. I haven't reinstalled Linux in so long, I'm so out of touch right now.

How large is Windows on SSD? If only one drive, both Windows & Ubuntu share that ESP in different folders. If only using grub the Windows default of 100MB on older Windows is large enough. ESP must be FAT32 with boot,esp flags. A /boot partition must be Linux format default in Ubuntu is ext4. I remove all snaps with Kubuntu and use about 16GB in / with 30 to 40GB as partition size. Then have all data in other drive or separate partiiton(s). You can most some Windows data to 2nd drive and have Linux data on 2nd drive so operating systems are on faster drive.

You can install grub on any drive, but it will only boot from the boot drive.
This is a function of your system firmware.  The EFI standard allows you to put the bootloaders for all operating systems in the same EFI partition.  If you have multiple EFI partitions, you will need to alter your bios settings to select which one is used.  Some bioses only support using the EFI partition on the first disk.
Having said that, the EFI partition typically only contains the bootloader which is very small.  You can move the /boot partition (which usually contains the kernel and initrd) to any disk, or sometimes even merge it with the main operating system disk.
The partition is called the EFI partition, but this has nothing to do with where it is mounted.  The standard is to mount it at /boot/efi and grub may not install correctly if you mount it at /efi instead.

Thank you, sure I will change the EFI partition used in BIOS. Separating /boot and /efi may not work on other Bootloaders, it works on GRUB2. /efi is used for the GRUB itself, it can look for kernels in /boot. I have a laptop with this kind of partition table, I made a mistake there by keeping a windows /efi which created problems down the line due to 300mb size. The separation of /efi and /boot was a solution to that.  Anyway, I don't have to worry about it here, should I make a /boot on an SSD and select it as a file path then&

efi and boot must be separate partitions.  Where they are mounted in the filesystem is irrelevant except to the grub configuration itself and the things that build that configuration.  Partition size is always an issue.
